# php htmlawed removing href link

Tags: php, sanitization

I am capturing some content using tinyMCE, and then posting the content back to php script to store in database.

I am using htmlawed to remove anything nasty.

The content of the $_POST variable is

```
<p>This is a link&nbsp;<a href=\"https://www.bbc.co.uk\">https://www.bbc.co.uk</a></p>
```

I am then using this code on the server

```
$Details = $_POST["Details"];

$config = array('elements'=>'* -script -object'); //dont allow any scripts
$SanitizedDetails = htmLawed($Details, $config);
```

SanitizedDetails then contains this

```
 <p>This is a link&nbsp;<a href="\">https://www.bbc.co.uk</a></p>
```

It has removed the contents of href (just left a backslash)

Please could somebody help with config for htmlawed

Comment: delete the first backslash \ from href=\ and the last one from uk\

Comment: Thank you - if you put it as an answer, I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the first backslash `\` from `href=\` and the last one from `uk\` and you're ready to go.